# SUM function and between two max dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, date, sum

I am trying to find out the total amount between 2 dates with MAX function in dates grouping by ID.
column 365date is the difference of column sessiondate-364.
Currently with this query I am getting the total amount, but I want to find out the amount between these 2-column date (i.e. 365 days).

This is my query:

```
SELECT
    DATEADD(day, -364, (MAX(sessiondate))) AS 365date,
    MAX(sessiondate)) AS lastdate,
    SUM(Amount) AS amount,
    ID  
FROM
    tablename 
WHERE
    date BETWEEN 365date AND lastdate 
GROUP BY 
    MemberID
```

date    |   LastDate|   Amount| ID| output amount(only last 365 days)|  Total amount(all year)

29/07/2020  |28/07/2021 |100    |1      |1500               |63000

29/08/2020  |28/07/2021 |500    |1

02/05/2020  |28/07/2021 |600    |1

15/01/2020  |28/07/2021 |300    |1

10/10/2000  |28/07/2021 |50000  |1

10/10/1989  |28/07/2021 |10000  |1

"So need to take max(lastdate) for this ID which is 28/07/2021
and subtract 365 days from that then take all the days which lies
between 365 (29/07/2020,29/08/2020,02/05/2020,15/01/2020) and do sum and show it in last 365 days column.
For column totalamount(all year) needs to add all amount no matter of 365 days

Logic:
calculate date column
(MAX(date))-364

calculate lastdate column
Max(lastdate)

calculate last365 amount column
Sum (amount) Between (MAX(date))-364 and Max(lastdate)

calculate Total amount(all year)
sum(amount)

```
I need only 1 row which is highlighted. Not sure whats wrong with the query.
```

[image]

Can someone please help with this?

Comment: Please improve your question...1) Tag your DBMS, 2) Show both sample input and expected outcome, 3) Explain what you want to do. What should this dateadd with 364 days mean? Do you want to go one year back and do not know the correct function for that?

Comment: So, the I assume the table in your question shows the expected result of the query? Please add a table which shows the input data. Generally, SQL questions should always include both input and outcome as tables. Not to create unnecessary work for you, but to be sure people will give correct and not misleading answers.

Comment: We need a [mre] with sample (raw) data, your desired results, the logic explanation and your attempt.

Comment: I  have updated my question with actual output and input

Comment: Thanks, but please read the first answer of this link here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post and format your tables as described.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CTE, I have convert your query to CTE for where clause.

```
;with cte AS (
SELECT
    DATEADD(day, -364, (MAX(sessiondate))) AS '365date',
    MAX(sessiondate)) AS 'lastdate',
    SUM(Amount) AS 'amount',
    ID  
FROM
    tablename
)
SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE
    DATE BETWEEN 365date AND lastdate 
GROUP BY 
    MemberID
```

Comment: thanks Hardik, In CTE I also need to show sum(AMOUNT) which is lifetime amount.
so 2 columns amount should be :
1st column sum of amount between 2 dates
2nd column sum of amount lifetime